# Joomla error "MODULO BY ZERO"

Tags: joomla

This error showed up as plain text on white background after logging in to the Maintenance Login window on the public front end of our Joomla 3.5.1 site. We are using a template from TemplateMonster called "theme3289"  (default version), aka "Truckie".

For no apparent reason, we found we could not log in to the Maintenance Login window on the public front end. We got the error:

"Modulo by zero" on a plain white background.

No part of the front public end of the site could be navigated to, even by pasting in a link.  However, we could navigate fine to the backend ([site_domain_name.com]/administrator)

Not sure exactly what caused this, but we did have the internet connection go down in the middle of saving an article. After re-gaining connection, the new article was missing. We had also made some simple content changes (not configuration or settings changes) in the articles inside the TM Parallax module.

Looking for help on this "Modulo by zero" error.

Answer (score 1):

RESTORED DATABASE BACKUP = Solved the problem. I am pretty sure it was some kind of database error or corruption. We tried clearing the cache (Joomla System Menu) and a number of other things. Nothing worked.

We had two staff working on the site at the time of the error, one a newbie, one an advanced beginner. Interviewing them with "what were you doing at the time" didn't seem to lend any clues. Unless perhaps the TM Parallax module may have a bug (???) - or a corruption somehow when internet went down while saving an article.

SOLUTION: We restored a recent backup copy of the database made only 2 hours prior to the ERROR. This solved our problem.

This worked for us.

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue today, and I found out the cause. Its simple actually,as the issue says your code somewhere is attempting to do division or modulo by 0. Maybe you had added a new field with value 0 in your db after taking backup and the data there was causing it. This may not be helpful for you now but I'm leaving this here to make it easy if someone has a similar issue and ends up here.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem was caused by a change in the template. For example, some templates do not allow specific values to be zero, and will crash when this happens.

A good idea to discover the root cause of the problem is to compare the templates settings of the backup to the template settings of the problematic site. If everything is exactly the same, then you should compare the modules, and finally the menu items. It is not a fun job to do, but will help you isolate the problem in case it happens again.

Comment: But i thought if the template setting was changed using the template manager in the joomla control panel - that this actually saves changes in the css files, right? And if that is the case, then this wouldn't be what caused our prob cuz we solved it by restoring a dbase backup - having nothing to do with the template... or perhaps I am not understanding what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

For your reference. Just had this issue and the above information did not help. Finally found the solution:

In Article > global Options > Blog/Featured layout I had the columns set to 0